# Getting Friend list having information in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have scenario in which I am storing `user` `email` in a table `user_info`. Its structure is given as below.

`user_info(_id,email)`

However one user can be friend of other users.So for that purpose i have another table `user_friend`. Its structure is given below

`user_friend(_id,userA , userB)`

Now suppose there are 5 user A,B,C,D and E. We got table values something like this.

> user_info

```
_id      email  
 1       A@...      
 2       B@...       
 3       C@...       
 4       D@...
 5       E@...
```

> user_friends

```
_id   userA   userB
 1       1       2
 2       1       3
 3       1       4
 4       5       1
```

it's mean A is friend of B,C,D and E. i want to get email of these but i am unable to think about any proper query.
i am using left join but it does not seems to work properly

> Getting friends of 1(A@...). But it's not working properly

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM user_info AS UI 
LEFT JOIN user_friends AS UF
ON UI._id = UF.userA 
LEFT JOIN user_friends AS UF2 
ON UI._id = UF2.userB
WHERE UF2.userA = '1' || UF2.userB ='1'
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: This one has been answered before

Comment: Well Thanks for the response i found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be Something like this.

> SELECT email from user_info WHERE _id IN (select userA from user_friends where userB = '1' Union All select userB from user_friends where userA = '1')

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to get all friends email

```
(SELECT
  u2.email
FROM user_info u
LEFT JOIN user_friends f ON f.userA = u._id
LEFT JOIN user_info u2 on u2._id = f.userB
WHERE u._id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT
    u2.email
FROM user_info u
LEFT JOIN user_friends f ON f.userB = u._id
LEFT JOIN user_info u2 ON u2._id = f.userA
WHERE u._id = 1)
```

Comment: Hey i really appreciate your answer but i guess i found a simpler one. Have a look at this one.
It will be Something like this.

>     SELECT email from user_info WHERE _id IN (select userA from user_friends where userB = '1' Union All select userB from user_friends where userA = '1')